# split an array with noncontinuous integers into arrays each with continuous integers

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have array in python with hundreds of elements that I would like to partition. Let's take the following array as an example: [1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,14], I would like to split into the following arrays:
[1,2,3], [7,8,9,10,11], [14], the idea is that within each array the numbers are continuous. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

I have not tried anything yet, I could write a for loop.

Comment: Then go write it and come back if you have some trouble doing so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups

a = [1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,14]

print(*map(list, consecutive_groups(a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use groupby from itertools to form groups using the difference between numbers and their position.  The consecutive numbers will have the same difference so they will end up in the same groups.

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,14]

group = (n-i for i,n in enumerate(a))
b     = [g for _,(*g,) in groupby(a,lambda _:next(group))]    

print(b)
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [14]]
```